# jQuery String Replace in TextArea

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to do a string replace in a textarea after the user has entered their content and nothing I've tried is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is where I am:

```
<textarea id="field_id_29"></textarea>

$("#field_id_29").bind("change keyup input",function(){
     var text = $("#field_id_29").val();
     text = text.replace(/source/g,"www")
     $("#field_id_29").val(text);
});
```

I need to replace **www-source** with **www**.

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6RNY2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#field_id_29").change(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var regexp = /www-source/gi;
    if ( text.match(regexp) ){      
        text = text.replace(/www-source/g,"www");
        return $(this).val(text);
    }
    return false;
});
```

When the field changes we grab the value, compare if against a regular expression and if we have a match we replace the text and we are done, otherwise we just return.

Comment: You already defined regexp, why don't you reuse variable on replace?

Comment: it changes the position of the cursor to the end of the text if the change happens at the start or in the middle :(

Answer (score 2):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RNY2/10/)

```
        $("#field_id_29").bind("change keyup input",function(){    
            this.value= this.value.replace(/www-source/g,"www");                 
        });
​
```

**Note:** inside function this is reference of textarea so you directly use this.value instead of accessing textarea value using id.

Comment: * .bind("keyup") seems enough. Why not $.change though?
* this.value instead of $(this).val(); care to explain what's the difference and what is faster?
* I guess it would be faster without the global match /g

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6RNY2/12/)**

```
[$("#field_id_29").bind("keyup", function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = text.replace(/source/g, "www")
    $(this).val(text);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you just need to use jQuery instead of Mootools in your jsfiddle, probably also just use the **change** event so that it replaces the text only after the textarea has been updated

Comment: Geez. I see that now. Wish I could get that hour back!